# In hummus js how can i draw a filled rectangle with transparent?

Tags: node.js, pdf, hummus.js

How can I draw a rectangle with a transparent color?

I tried the below code. I am using **hummusjs** for modifying pdf.

```
cxt.drawRectangle(x,y,width,height,{type: 'fill',
           color: '#eeeeee',
           opacity: 0.9});
```

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to draw a rectangle without fill and only containing borders, try this:

```
cxt.drawRectangle(x,y,width,height,{type: 'stroke',
       color: '#eeeeee',
       opacity: 0.9});
```